# Call nosetests as a scons task.

Tags: python, scons, nose

I would like to get scons to call nosetests with a list of directories.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to analyze return code of external application (if you calling tests, for example), you need to use Command() + python subprocess module. 
If you using only Command you can't get return code of application.

For example:

```
if 'test' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
    runTestsCmd = env.Command('runTests', None, Action(runTests, "Running tests"))
    AlwaysBuild(runTestsCmd)
    Alias('test', runTestsCmd)
```

runTests function example:

```
def runTests(target = None, source = None, env = None) :
    # fill args
    retCode = subprocess.call(args, env = env['ENV'], cwd = cwd, shell = True)
    Exit(retCode)
```

Also, you can set additional dependencies for runTestsCmd.

```
Depends(runTestsCmd, [appAndLibsToBuild])
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the nose framework, but there are two ways to execute external applications with SCons (there are other ways to do it with python, but no need to mention those) as follows:

- [Execute](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x3090.html)() - executes always while analyzing the SConscript files
- [Command](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3786.html)() - acts like a target and only executes according to its dependencies

I would think you would want to use the Command() option to only launch the unit tests if one of the related dependencies changed.

Regarding the list of directories, then you can use some python programming, like this:

```
dirs = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']
for dir in dirs:
   cmd = 'theScriptToExecute $SOURCE $TARGET'
   env.Command(target = 'whatever', source = dir, action = cmd)
```